# Connecting an Ubuntu laptop to network through Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, toshiba-laptop

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Lite and a Toshiba laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The Pi is connected to my home WiFi network. How can I connect them (for instance through an Ethernet cable) so that the laptop uses the Pi's network connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your Raspberry wifi router. There is one howto:

https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/